# How to prevent Data in const to change if underlaying data changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running into a strange issue. I have a function that updates my data on a Couchbase back end and before I do so I query if we have the record or if will be a new one. In my code I check via `if (docid[1].metrics.resultCount === 1)` if we have a record or not and then I assign the result to `const originalData` via `const originalData = docid[0][0].Record`. So far so good, if I print to my console the data at that point the data is correct. But if I go and print it after some changes where made to the `docid[0][0]` it also seems to update the `originalData`. Question is how can I store the Data in `const originalData` without being effected by changes to the `docid[0][0]`?

```
 case '2':
              // Title Pro Farm Updates or Inserts

              // Get the Translation Template

              const templateId = "c90207b5-71d1-43d6-b644-f92cf415ecab"
              const mappings = await couch.getDoc('contacts', 'import_mapping::' + templateId)
              const data_map = mappings.result.value

              // Transform based on mappings
              let map_result = mapdata(data_map , json)
              // TODO: Remove Debug Print Out
              //console.log(JSON.stringify(map_result))

              
              myApn = json.APN
              // Strip Dashes from APN String
              myApn = myApn.replace(/-/g, "")
              // Get the DocId for the Doc which matches APN
              docid = await couch.n1qlQuery_wId('contacts', myN1qlStr, [myApn])
           

              if (docid[1].metrics.resultCount === 1) {
                const originalData = docid[0][0].Record
                console.log('Before Updates')
                console.log(originalData)

                DocId = docid[0][0].DocId
                console.log(' We are updating APN ' + myApn)
                // get update Object based on Import
                let update = await imp_help.farm_update_titlepro(map_result, res.locals.decoded.user_guid)

              
                // console.log(docid[0][0])

                // Mailing Address
                let MailingAddrObj = update.mailingAddress
                Object.keys(MailingAddrObj).forEach(key => MailingAddrObj[key] === undefined && delete MailingAddrObj[key])
                let MailingAddress = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.mailingAddress, MailingAddrObj)

                // Owner Section
                let OwnerObj = update.Owners
                Object.keys(OwnerObj).forEach(key => OwnerObj[key] === undefined && delete OwnerObj[key])
                let Owner = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.Owners, OwnerObj)

                // Sales Info
                let SalesInfoObj = update.SalesInfo
                Object.keys(SalesInfoObj).forEach(key => SalesInfoObj[key] === undefined && delete SalesInfoObj[key])
                let SalesInfo = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.SalesInfo, SalesInfoObj)

             

                // Tax Info
                let TaxesObj = update.Taxes
                Object.keys(TaxesObj).forEach(key => TaxesObj[key] === undefined && delete TaxesObj[key])
                let Taxes = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.Taxes, TaxesObj)

                // History
                let HistoryObj = update.History
                Object.keys(HistoryObj).forEach(key => HistoryObj[key] === undefined && delete HistoryObj[key])
                let History = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.History, HistoryObj)


                // Farm Object
                let FarmObj = update
                Object.keys(FarmObj).forEach(key => FarmObj[key] === undefined && delete FarmObj[key])
                let Farm = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record, FarmObj)

                console.log('After Updates')
                console.log(originalData)

                Farm.mailingAddress = MailingAddress
                Farm.Owners = Owner
                Farm.emails = []
                Farm.phones = []
                Farm.SalesInfo = SalesInfo
                Farm.Taxes = Taxes
                Farm.History = History

                console.log(Farm)

                //let upsertResult = await couch.upsertDoc('contacts', DocId, Farm)
                // console.log(upsertResult)


              }
              else if (docid[1].metrics.resultCount == 0) {

                console.log("No Record Found")

                console.log(' We are creating New APN ' + myApn)
                // get update Object based on Import
                let newRecord = await imp_help.farm_create_titlepro(json, res.locals.decoded.user_guid)

                DocId = newRecord._type + "::" + newRecord._id
                console.log(DocId)
                let upsertResult = await couch.upsertDoc('contacts', DocId, newRecord)
                console.log(upsertResult)

              }
              break;
```

Comment: Non-primatives are stored by reference. `const` prevents you from assigning a new thing to a variable but not from changing the internals of the thing. You'd need to make a "deep copy" of the thing in order to keep a version that is unedited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when we assign one object to another, such as in your case, we'll have a **copying by reference**, because both variables are assigned to **reference** the same object. Hence, the following code will result in the following output:

```
const ghostbusters = {number: 4};
const tmnt = {number: 4};
let fantastic4 = tmnt;
```

[image: Copying by reference in JavaScript objects]

So, changing `fantastic4` will be like changing `tmnt` which will result in that error. This is not the case for **primitives** like strings and numbers.

For your case, to avoid this, you should use `Object.assign` or `spread operators`.

```
const tmnt = {number: 4};
const fantastic4 = {...tmnt};
```

[image: 2 objects referencing 2 different data]

I suggest you try this:

```
const originalData = {...docid[0][0].Record}
// or
const originalData = Object.assign({}, docid[0][0].Record)
```

This will create a clone of your data instead of referencing the same one.

Comment: Thanks, i figured something like this was the case. While searching i also came across this one Object.freeze(myObject); and wondering if this will do the same or if there is a drawback freezing the Object to prevent chabges

Comment: If you are sure that you don't want that object to be changed, there is no harm in that. But declaring that with const would already do that for you.
Also, this does not solve your problem since both objects will still be referencing the same data and trying to mutate it will throw an error.

Comment: The start of this answer is misleading -- many languages pass objects by reference and it's a feature of the language and not unexpected.  This is also true of C++ despite the beginning of this answer.  I'm removing the first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your edit @Joe. I didn't know that C++ works the same way in objects assignments. I will read about it.

Comment: C++ has specific semantics for declaring parameters as pass-by-reference but that doesn't make it necessarily easier to understand.  In many languages objects are passed by reference (or object reference) -- see Python or Ruby also

Comment: Ok, just as a note on this , neither of these will create deep copy's which means an object within this object will still be altered if the original object is changed.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Object.assign` like below:

```
const originalData = Object.assign({}, docid[0][0].Record);
```

it makes a copy of the object